# update elements of a table that is connected with bridge table

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.6

I have following tables:

```
BOOK: id,name
USER: id,username,status
BOOK_USER: book_id, user_id
```

I want to have functionality in my application where use can set the reading status. Example. Start reading stop reading.

In my `Book.java` I have introduced `USER` table as a `ManyToMany`

```
  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "user",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  public List<User> users;
```

and in my User.java

```
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
  public List<Book> bookList;
```

When user set the stop reading on start reading I want to update the User table. This method get called from my `BookController.java` update method.

```
  public void changeReadingStatus() {
    for (User user : users) {
      user.setStatus("Finished Reading");
      user.update();
    }
  }
```

I get an error

```
Caused by: io.ebean.DataIntegrityException: Error when batch flush on sql: insert into BOOK_USER (book_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
        at io.ebean.config.dbplatform.SqlCodeTranslator.translate(SqlCodeTranslator.java:44)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure it this way

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "BOOK_USER",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
public List<User> users;



@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
public List<Book> bookList;
```

more info [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html)